# Python - reading a special key with get_wch or getkey

Tags: python, curses

Suppose I have following setup:

```
import curses

window = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()

while True:
    k = window.get_wch()
    print("k: ", k)
```

Now, according to the documentation, `get_wch` should return a character on normal characters, and an integer for special keys. However, when I run the above snippet and press, say, arrow up, the loop above fires up three times and gives three separate characters, instead of an integer. The same happens when I use `getkey`: three characters instead of a multibyte string (as docs say it should return). How do I read a special key? Is it a bug, or do I miss something obvious? I'm running the code on Linux and Python 3.6.1, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output something so it is read in the next loop iteration! Flush/clear the input after you print something…

```
import curses

window = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
window.keypad(True)  # Maybe not perfect, but a good start?

while True:
    k = window.get_wch()
    print(f'k: {k}')
    curses.flushinp()
```

Comment: The problem is not extra looping, the problem is that I can't read special keys in this manner.

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing piece. Now it works.